# Mysql_fetch_array php and jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, jquery-autocomplete

SO I have Jquery autocomplete working with mysql using mysql_fetch_array, I know I know,

I am having a little trouble returning every column in a row, so far a request on the on the name column of a table takes place, and returns the name column from the row.

My "events" Table looks like this,

```
name     event    price    date    color    drinks
```

what I want to do  is search, "name", "event" "date" and "color" columns
but when a match is found in any column, to display results from them columns in a certain an order.

So if my "events" table contained the following data

```
name     event       price     date             color         drinks
Helen    Topmark      31       03/02/2013       red            brandy
Gregg    maxpower     27       01/02/2013       red            whiskey
```

and somebody searches for "red helen" the autocomplete would fill like this

```
Helen Topmark red 03/02/2013
```

Also if somebody searches "red" I would like to prioritize the date

```
Gregg maxpower red 01/02/2013
Helen Topmark red 03/02/2013
```

Here is the code I currently have

```
$req = "SELECT name "
    ."FROM events "
    ."WHERE name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' "; 

$query = mysql_query($req);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Thank you very much for your`e time.

Comment: Have you started any of your jQuery code? Or Html?

Comment: OT You should never put user input right into a query like that. It should be escaped first, or better, you should use a parameterized query. Read up on SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$req = "SELECT name, event, color, date FROM events WHERE (name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' OR event LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' OR date LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' OR color LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%')";
```

And your while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['event'] . ' ' . $row['color'] . ' ' . $row['date']; 
}
```

Just giving some direction, still open to sql injection.

Comment: how u get $row[event] or $row[color] ? u have selected `name` in select statement, u hav to select those things also in select statement

Answer (score 0):

Update you query like below:

```
$search  =  $_REQUEST['term'];
$pieces = explode(" ", $search);
$in = "";
foreach($pieces as $val) {
    $in = "'".$val."' IN (name,color) AND ";
    if(end($pieces) === $val)
        $in = "'".$val."' IN (name,color)";
}
```

NOTE: mysql_query() these functions are deprecated from PHP5.3.